# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' when trying to use a NodeJS library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I initiated a basic ReactJS app using `npx create-react-app`, then I ejected using `npm run eject`. Now when I am trying to import the [Casual](https://github.com/boo1ean/casual) library by `import casual from 'casual';`, I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/casual/src/casual.js 3:13-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' 
in '/home/me/project/node_modules/casual/src'
```

And the code around line number 3 in `casual.js` looks like this:

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var exists = require('fs').existsSync;

var safe_require = function(filename) {
    if (exists(filename + '.js')) {
        return require(filename);
    }
    return {};
};
...
```

I found answers to similar questions. Those were mainly Node or Angular related. I also tried answers suggesting some changes in webpack config, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `Casual` doesn't work on the front end. It runs on Node.js only.
You need to install maybe a new package to make things work.

`Fs` is unavailable on the browser so it won't work. Instead, you should use [casual-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/casual-browserify), it will work on browsers.